# what is the difference between tar and gZ?

Tags: iphone

when i compress the file "file.tar.gZ" in iphone SDK, it gives file.tar , but both tar and tar.gZ gives same size?any help please?

Answer (score 12):

[*.tar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(file_format)) means that multiple files are combined to one. (Tape Archive)

[*.gz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) means that the files are compressed as well. (GZip compression)

Edit: that the size is the same doesn't say a lot. Sometimes files can't be compressed.

Comment: Yes, in rare cases compressed data will actually be larger than uncompressed! For example, if you are compressing small strings, or files that at already compressed (mp3, jpg, etc).

Answer (score 4):

As Rhapsody said, `tar` is an archive containing multiple files, and `gz` is a file that is compressed using gzip. The reason why two formats are used is because gzip only supports compressing one file - perhaps due to the UNIX philosophy that a program should do one thing, and do it well.

In any case, if you have the option you may want to use bzip2 compression, which is more efficient (IE, compresses files to a smaller size) than gzip.